# JTable Nimbus Look and Feel - how to make it clear which cell has focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable, nimbus, tablecelleditor

When editing data in a JTable (Nimbus L & F), as the user tabs from cell to cell, it is not obvious which cell has focus. How can I make it clearer which cell has focus? I know there are a number of properties that can be set to modify Nimbus - does anyone know which property I want?

The screen shot below has only one property set to something other than the default:

```
UIManager.put("Table.showGrid", true);
```

[image: JTable screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have look at [Renderer concept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender),
- by defaul works for [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html),
- some issue could be with [JButtons components (JCheckBox e.i.)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), but a few times are answered or solved on this forum

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class ImageChangeDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table = new javax.swing.JTable();
    private JTable table1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    private static Icon ascendingSortIcon;
    private static Icon descendingSortIcon;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //comment out the code below to try in Metal L&F
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    ascendingSortIcon = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon");
                    descendingSortIcon = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getIcon("Table.descendingSortIcon");
                    //UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.ascendingSortIcon", new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.UP, false, false));
                    //UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.descendingSortIcon", new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.DOWN, false, false));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageChangeDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public ImageChangeDemo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane pane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        //table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {"a", "q", "h", "v"},
                    {"b", "m", "l", "h"},
                    {"d", "c", "a", "d"},
                    {"j", "o", "y", "e"}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4"
                }) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            Class[] types = new Class[]{
                String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class
            };

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel()) {

            @Override
            public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
                if (column >= 0 && column < getModelWrapper().getColumnCount() && isSortable(column)) {
                    List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
                    if (!keys.isEmpty()) {

                        SortKey sortKey = keys.get(0);
                        if (sortKey.getColumn() == column && sortKey.getSortOrder() == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
                            setSortKeys(null);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                super.toggleSortOrder(column);
            }
        };
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        pane.setViewportView(table);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.ascendingSortIcon", new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.UP, false, false));
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.descendingSortIcon", new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.DOWN, false, false));
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(table);
        add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JScrollPane pane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        //table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {"a", "q", "h", "v"},
                    {"b", "m", "l", "h"},
                    {"d", "c", "a", "d"},
                    {"j", "o", "y", "e"}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4"
                }) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            Class[] types = new Class[]{
                String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class
            };

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        table1.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table1.getPreferredSize());
        pane1.setViewportView(table1);
        add(pane1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        for (int i = 0; i < table1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            RowColorRenderer rowRenderer = new RowColorRenderer(i);
            TableColumn column = table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer(rowRenderer);
        }
        pack();
    }

    private class RowColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int colNo = 0;

        RowColorRenderer(int col) {
            colNo = col;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;
            if (!isSelected) {
                if (table.getValueAt(row, colNo) != null) {
                    String str = table.getValueAt(row, colNo).toString();
                    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                        if (Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(str).find()) {
                            if (((Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && (!(Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.magenta);
                                setBackground(Color.orange);
                            } else if ((!(Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && ((Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.blue);
                                setBackground(Color.yellow);
                            } else if (((Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && ((Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.red);
                                setBackground(Color.cyan);
                            }
                            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
                            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                        } else {
                            setBackground(table.getBackground());
                            setForeground(table.getForeground());
                            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 8));
                            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
                    setForeground(Color.magenta);
                    setBackground(Color.orange);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    static class BevelArrowIcon implements Icon {

        public static final int UP = 0;         // direction
        public static final int DOWN = 1;
        private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 11;
        private Color edge1;
        private Color edge2;
        private Color fill;
        private int size;
        private int direction;

        public BevelArrowIcon(int direction, boolean isRaisedView, boolean isPressedView) {
            if (isRaisedView) {
                if (isPressedView) {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlLtHighlight"), UIManager.getColor("controlDkShadow"), UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"), DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                } else {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlHighlight"), UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"), UIManager.getColor("control"), DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                }
            } else {
                if (isPressedView) {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlDkShadow"), UIManager.getColor("controlLtHighlight"), UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"), DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                } else {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"), UIManager.getColor("controlHighlight"), UIManager.getColor("control"), DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                }
            }
        }

        public BevelArrowIcon(Color edge1, Color edge2, Color fill, int size, int direction) {
            init(edge1, edge2, fill, size, direction);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            switch (direction) {
                case DOWN:
                    drawDownArrow(g, x, y);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    drawUpArrow(g, x, y);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return size;
        }

        private void init(Color edge1, Color edge2, Color fill, int size, int direction) {
            edge1 = Color.red;
            edge2 = Color.blue;
            this.edge1 = edge1;
            this.edge2 = edge2;
            this.fill = fill;
            this.size = size;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        private void drawDownArrow(Graphics g, int xo, int yo) {
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo, xo + size - 1, yo);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + 1, xo + size - 3, yo + 1);
            g.setColor(edge2);
            g.drawLine(xo + size - 2, yo + 1, xo + size - 1, yo + 1);
            int x = xo + 1;
            int y = yo + 2;
            int dx = size - 6;
            while (y + 1 < yo + size) {
                g.setColor(edge1);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + 1, y);
                g.drawLine(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                if (0 < dx) {
                    g.setColor(fill);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y, x + 1 + dx, y);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y + 1, x + 1 + dx, y + 1);
                }
                g.setColor(edge2);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y, x + dx + 3, y);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y + 1, x + dx + 3, y + 1);
                x += 1;
                y += 2;
                dx -= 2;
            }
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo + (size / 2), yo + size - 1, xo + (size / 2), yo + size - 1);
        }

        private void drawUpArrow(Graphics g, int xo, int yo) {
            g.setColor(edge1);
            int x = xo + (size / 2);
            g.drawLine(x, yo, x, yo);
            x--;
            int y = yo + 1;
            int dx = 0;
            while (y + 3 < yo + size) {
                g.setColor(edge1);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + 1, y);
                g.drawLine(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                if (0 < dx) {
                    g.setColor(fill);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y, x + 1 + dx, y);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y + 1, x + 1 + dx, y + 1);
                }
                g.setColor(edge2);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y, x + dx + 3, y);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y + 1, x + dx + 3, y + 1);
                x -= 1;
                y += 2;
                dx += 2;
            }
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + size - 3, xo + 1, yo + size - 3);
            g.setColor(edge2);
            g.drawLine(xo + 2, yo + size - 2, xo + size - 1, yo + size - 2);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + size - 1, xo + size, yo + size - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and then some. You even through in a custom sorting icon just for fun:) (The Nimbus Default is fine, but thanks anyway.) Nice example to illustrate what is possible.

Comment: glad to help you, notice I'm still not sure, if you'll need to do the same things for TableCellEditor :-)

Comment: I would need to do the same things with TableCellEditor if I want the focus color to remain while editing.  At this point, I completely understand HOW to do this, what's left is the decision of exactly WHAT do to. TableCellEditor explains why after the user starts editing a focused cell, the look changes (from the selected row color to a white background). That's probably what I want-I'm not sure it matters much. This question wasn't really about appearance, it was about making the table more intuitive and usable since some of my users are, let's say not savvy.

Comment: some things are simply ..unattainable for me, leading with my (great, excelent, incomparable, e.i. rest of superlatives) written and spoken english,

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom cell renderer class which will change the foreground colour for instance if selected.

Your class will *extend DefaultTableCellRenderer* and *override the method getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)*.

e.g.

```
public class SpreadsheetCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        /* the following is the similar to DefaultTableCellRenderer */
        if (isSelected) {
            super.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            super.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
    setText(value.toString());
    return this;
    }
}
```

Then you need to set that renderer as the default renderer for say the String objects in the table by doing this.

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Class.forName("java.lang.String"), new SpreadsheetCellRenderer());
```

Comment: By the way, I'm obviously showing a mechanism outside of Nimbus, but this is a general way to change the properties of a JTable.

Comment: I am aware of TableCellRenderer and was looking for an easier way, but thank you for the clear example. It's easier to create a custom cell renderer than I thought. But I was hoping for something from here: http://jasperpotts.com/blogfiles/nimbusdefaults/nimbus.html

Comment: @Thorn I'll undelete my answer here, no issue

Comment: I don't do much with look and feel, I've always developed my own components and used renderers to change the look. But can you not do this? UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table[Selected].textForeground", "#ff0000");